Можно ли в asyncio сделать два ожидания по timeout
Изучаю asyncio , и понадобилось решить следующую задачу.
Если время работы корутины более 3 сек, нужно завершить задачу.
Остальные задачи нужно завершить после 10 сек (общее время работы программы 10 сек).
Примерно такой код.
async def some_coro(time):
    print(f"Корутина {asyncio.current_task().get_name()} запустилась")
    try:
       await asyncio.sleep(time)
       print(f"Корутина {asyncio.current_task().get_name()} завершилась")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
       print(f"Корутина {asyncio.current_task().get_name()} отменена")
    

async def wait_10():
    print('начало отсчета 10 сек')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print ('10 сек прошло. Завершаем все задачи')
    for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
        try:
            task.cancel()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass

async def main():
   tasks = [asyncio.create_task(some_coro(12)), asyncio.create_task(some_coro(2)), asyncio.create_task(some_coro(15))]
    #await asyncio.create_task(wait_10())
   await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=5)

asyncio.run(main())  

Если я просто запускаю один asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=5). то просто незавершенные задачи отменяются через 5 сек (но нет общего счетчика в 10 сек)
Если я добавляю await asyncio.create_task(wait_10()), то такое ощущение, что timeout в asyncio.wait "уже не работает", и у меня все задачи завершаются после 10 сек, а не по таймауту 5 сек.
Первое, хотелось бы понять для себя, почему так происходит?
А второе, можно ли сделать "два отдельных" счетчика? Чувствую, что упускаю какие-то основы asyncio, и хотелось бы разобраться. Заранее спасибо.

Исправьте для начала код на корректный. Вот это except except и main_task - это не запустится вообще. А так то объясните, чего вы хотите добиться? await asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=5) ждёт либо завершения всех задач, либо 5 секунд - что наступит раньше. И возвращает два списка - завершённых задач и незавершённых задач. Что вы хотите сделать?

Если вы добавляете await asyncio.create_task(wait_10()) это вы буквально добавляете ожидание, пока эта строка завершится, потом уже запускается await asyncio.wait(). Если вам нужно, чтобы wait_10 тоже параллельно ожидалось - добавьте его в тот же список tasks. Либо уберите await перед asyncio.create_task, тогда она эта задача как бы в фоне будет работать. Можно эту задачу записать в переменную, а в конце сделать await для нее, чтобы дождаться завершения.

Тут главное решить - какие задачи вы ждёте, какие нет. Потому что когда сработает таймаут, ожидание прекратится. И если ничего дальше не делать, то код закончит работу и, вроде бы, и таски все прекратятся, хотя я тут не уверен. Поэтому не совсем понятно, зачем вы тут прерываете ожидание по таймауту. Дальше то вы что хотите делать - дождаться, пока таска wait_10 завершится?

Кстати, когда вы канселите все подряд таски через task.cancel(), учтите, что если вы чего-то ждёте через await в этот момент, то и это ожидание вы тоже так убьёте и эксепшен вылетит в том месте кода, где идёт это ожидание )  И корутину wait_10 вы тоже саму так закенселите.

@CrazyElf, да, извините за ошибки. Это опечатки, при оформлении вопроса невнимательно исправил.. Хотел попробовать сделать что-то вроде: если корутина выполняется больше 3 сек, то она отменяется. Остальные "успешные" корутины отменяются после 10 сек

@Иван Какая-то нечёткая формулировка. Какие корутины должны остаться в живых после 3 сек? )

@CrazyElf, да, согласен,описание не совсем удачное). В реальной жизни, например, это что-то вроде: подключаемся к трем серверам, если какой-то сервер не ответил в течение 3-х сек, считаем, что он не доступен, и останавливаем задачу (я думал это сделать по таймауту в asyncio.wait). Остальные успешные задачи (где подключение произошло в течение 3 сек и идет, например, какой-то обмен сообщениями) завершить после 10 сек и завершить программу (это уже думал сделать при помощи корутины wait_10). Тут, наверное, еще путанницу вносит, что я и "успешные" задачи в примере просто завершаю принтом.

То есть мини аналог такой 10-секундной программы, чтобы понять, какой сервер (оборудование, сайт и тд) доступен, какой нет. И хотелось бы понять, как это сделать именно ассинхронно, тк изучаю сейчас asyncio :)

А, ну вот "сервер не ответил" - это через wait_for по идее, да, сам коннект к серверу через ожидание с таймаутом делать и выходить из задачи, если сработал таймаут. Ну, я вроде примеры работы в ответе написал, наверное должно что-то понятнее стать.

@CrazyElf, спасибо большое, я уже изучаю! Надо вчитаться вдумчиво)


Если я просто запускаю один asyncio.wait(tasks, timeout=5), то просто незавершенные задачи отменяются через 5 сек

Нет, отменяются не задачи, отменяется их ожидание через asyncio.wait. И возвращаются два списка: завершённых задач и не завершённых.
Если хотите, чтобы после timeout произошла отмена задач, используйте asyncio.wait_for, вот эта функция отменит задачи, которые будут работать дольше, чем timeout.

Если я добавляю await asyncio.create_task(wait_10()), то такое ощущение, что timeout в asyncio.wait "уже не работает", и у меня все задачи завершаются после 10 сек, а не по таймауту 5 сек.

Конечно, так и есть, потому что вы сначала ожидаете окончания работы задачи wait_10 и только после этого начинает работать следующие ожидание задач, а на тот момент все задачи вы уже убили-с в задаче wait_10. Кстати, вы там убиваете все задачи без разбора, включая саму задачу wait_10 и любые задачи в активном статусе, в том числе текущий await.
Вот вам пример кода, из которого может что-то будет более понятно. Только я тут main() запускаю немного по-другому, потому что работаю через Jupyter Notebook, там ваш способ запуска не работает.
Да, и заодно я исправил ошибки, неправильные названия вызываемых функций и т.п.
import asyncio

async def main_task(time):
    print(f"Корутина {asyncio.current_task().get_name()} запустилась")
    try:
       await asyncio.sleep(time)
       print(f"Корутина {asyncio.current_task().get_name()} завершилась")
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
       print(f"Корутина {asyncio.current_task().get_name()} отменена")
    

async def wait_10():
    print('начало отсчета 10 сек')
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print ('10 сек прошло. Завершаем все задачи')
    for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
        try:
            name = task.get_name()
            if task.get_name().startswith('MT'):
                print(f'Отменяем задачу {name}')
                task.cancel()
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pass

def show_stats(tasks):
    print(f'Запущено задач: {sum(not t.done() for t in tasks)}')

async def main():
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(main_task(12), name='MT12'), 
             asyncio.create_task(main_task(2), name='MT2'), 
             asyncio.create_task(main_task(15), name='MT15')]
    kill_task = asyncio.create_task(wait_10())
    show_stats(tasks)
    await kill_task
    show_stats(tasks)
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    print('Завершаем работу')

await main()

Вывод:
Запущено задач: 3
Корутина MT12 запустилась
Корутина MT2 запустилась
Корутина MT15 запустилась
начало отсчета 10 сек
Корутина MT2 завершилась
10 сек прошло. Завершаем все задачи
Отменяем задачу MT15
Отменяем задачу MT12
Корутина MT15 отменена
Корутина MT12 отменена
Запущено задач: 0
Завершаем работу

Я дал задачам имена, чтобы отличать те задачи, которые нужно принудительно завершать, от других задач, которые лучше не трогать.
Добавил статистику запущенных задач. В конце ожидание задач уже так, на всякий случай. На этот момент все задачи уже принудительно завершены.
